# Are XML documentation tags not being handled by Web API 2 help pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm trying to use `<see cref="">` tags in my XML documentation tags for my API, but they are coming up blank in the Help pages.

So, for a Description I'd like it to say:

"Gets or sets the value for the associated *Item*."

Where *Item* is a link to another object in the API.

Instead, I'm getting:

"Gets or sets the value for the associated ."

So the `<see cref="">` tag is being ignored. I've even tried using examples from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) just in case my declaration was wrong, but that didn't work either.

Has anybody else had issues with this? To what level are XML documentation tags supported in the new Web API 2 Help Pages? Does anybody know if it's possible to add support for this manually, if not?

Comment: We do have the same issue, but all blog posts around this topic seemed to be outdated.

Comment: I outline a way of doing this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177104/asp-web-api-help-pages-links-to-other-pages/26255631#26255631

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had issues with this, but I suggest you

- Post a simple sample that illustrates the behavior, together with the result you obtain
- Check for build warnings that might indicate problems with your XML documentation tags.

For example, you say you're using `<see cref="">`  Are you putting a valid identifier in the cref attribute and closing the see tag - e.g. `<see cref="MyClass.MyMethod" />`?

Comment: Hey Joe, we have the same issue and it seems that other people are seeing this also. In case you have any hints on where to start?